Version Compatibility - postgres / psql Version Mismatch
I'm working on a system where I'm neither privileged user nor admin.
I was trying to use pg_dump, and got the following message:
pg_dump: server version: 15.5; pg_dump version 11.17
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
Sent this to the administrators of the system, and was told:
"We are currently testing a postgres update for another team, the major version is 14" Would that work for you as well?"
Been searching for two days, running out of search iterations. My question is, can anyone direct me to a compatibility matrix/table that will show if server version 15.5 is compatible with "major version 14"?

Postgres 14 and 15 are different major versions so they are not compatible at the server level. Your issue though is with the client program pg_dump. You cannot use an older version of pg_dump(11.17) to dump a newer Postgres server(15.5). You can go the other way though, so find the 15 version of pg_dump and use it to dump the Postgres 11.17 server. For more information see pg_dump Notes section.

Thanks for the reply.Another question. If pg_dump is  not compatible, then would all of the other client programs also not be compatible? My guess is not.

No, other client programs are also not compatible. None can predict the future to see if it supports some new unknown functionality or object that must be part of a backup.

pg_dump and the other clients can be compatible depending on the direction, in that they know about the past but not the future. If the Postgres 11 and 15 server instances are on the same  machine you should find out whether the corresponding client programs are also installed. Otherwise you can install them on another machine and do the dump from there.

Thanks to all. I'm good to go now. Appreciate your input. Have a good rest of the week.

Client compatibility is generally not a problem, other than for special clients like pg_dump, pg_basebackup, and pg_waldump.  If you are just using psql, for example, you should not experience problems except for the metacommands (\d, etc) which need to do introspection.  Tab completion can also go awry sometimes.

From the manual: However, pg_dump cannot dump from PostgreSQL servers newer than its own major version; it will refuse to even try, rather than risk making an invalid dump. 
That means you need at least pg_dump version 15 to make a dump from a PostgreSQL version 15 database. A pg_dump version 15 is compatible with older PostgreSQL versions, just not with newer versions.

Good answer, but duplicate question.
